# Hard to get Pi out of case

Tags: case

I bought this [case](https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/premium-black-raspberry-pi-case-for-2b-3b-3b).

[image: Raspberry Pi Black Case]
Now I've got the upper part off the Pi, but the bottom part isn't that easy to get off the Pi.

Is there anyway to easily remove the case or is the best way just pulling very hard?

Comment: Why not ask the seller? Otherwise you are hoping someone who does own one will see this question. Another option is to search youtube for a review of the case that may address the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find a small [flat-headed screwdriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipdqb.jpg) to be extremely helpful in these situations.

Just find a small crack between the case and the Raspberry Pi, then carefully insert the screwdriver.  Use the screwdriver as a fulcrum to lift the Raspberry Pi out of the case (keeping the case stationary). *Please be gentle*.

Comment: @Loko How did it go?

Comment: I tried it but there isn't really a small crack. The only spot is under the place where the SD card should be. I didn't want to lift it too hard there. There are some plastic pieces to stop the raspberry from getting lifted. If I really cant figure out how to get it out the right way then I am just gonna do this again, but just lift it all the way.

Comment: I agree, Loko. I can't get it out either because of the white things holding the Raspberry Pi in place.

Answer (score 4):

I used 2 x spludgers on the HDMI side to get the 2 x lock tabs away from where they lock onto the base and then slowly ease it out of the base with a final lift out on the ethernet/ub side as per Lazloman

Answer (score 3):

Wiggle the board gently to get it off of the mounts. Slide the breadboard away from the power and HDMI slots, gently lift the back by the SD slot, then angle the board up and out pulling the USB and network port and lift out of the case.

Solution discovered by one of my students.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I ran into this problem as well, and what I did to get it out was:

Use my thumbs to pull the case outward and then have someone else work the case loose from the ethernet/usb side.

Hope this helps someone.